# java jdbc check if value exists before inserting into table

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm working on a Java project and I've hit a wall regarding inserting values into my table. I wanted to have a check before inserting into this table to see if there were any duplicates.

I've tried an executeUpdate with a resultset for executequery afterwards, but I'm getting "java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery()."

Here is the code I'm working with, thank you in advanced!

```
    public void registernow(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException, SQLException {
    ConnectionClass registerClass = new ConnectionClass();
    Connection register = registerClass.getConnection();

    try {
        Statement registerStatement = register.createStatement();
        String sql = "INSERT INTO userAuth (username, password) VALUES ('" + txt_username.getText() + "' , '" + txt_password.getText() + "')";
        registerStatement.executeUpdate(sql);

        ResultSet resultSet = registerStatement.executeQuery(sql);

        if (resultSet.next()) {
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("register.fxml"));
            Parent fxmlregister = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setTitle("COMP228 Project Registration Complete!");
            stage.setScene(new Scene(fxmlregister));
            stage.show();
        } else {
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("registerfailed.fxml"));
            Parent fxmlregisterfailed = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setTitle("COMP228 Project Registration Failed!");
            stage.setScene(new Scene(fxmlregisterfailed));
            stage.show();
        }
```

Comment: You'll need an extra "SELECT count(*) userAuth WHERE username = user AND password = pw" statement and check if it's zero.
And you should be using [PreparedStatements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: What is unclear from the message? You're not checking anything before inserting. You're inserting (executeUpdate()), and then trying to execute the same insert query a second time, but this time using executeQuery, which can only execute select statements. You also really, really need to learn about prepared statements (what if the name is O'Reilly?), and unles this is some toy project, you really really shouldn't store passwords in a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error and @JBNizet already told you, you are trying to execute the same update statement but with the `ExecuteQuery`.

So you are trying to execute an update statement with a `executeQuery`, you should try your second command with a query

```
sql = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM yourTable WHERE yourCondition = true";
ResultSet resultSet = registerStatement.executeQuery(sql);
```

And you sould really take notes of the comment of @JBNizet, is bad to concat strings to create queries.

Answer (score 2):

The [Answer by rekiem87](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53733666/642706) is correct, as are the two comments on the Question.

## UPSERT

Besides those points, if you wish to update an existing record  or otherwise insert a new one, [that behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(SQL)) is commonly known as an `UPSERT` (meaning, UPdate or else inSERT) or a “merge”.

As I recall, such a feature is not defined in the SQL standard. But many databases have implemented one.

For example, in Postgres, use [`INSERT ON CONFLICT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html). See [this first look](http://www.craigkerstiens.com/2015/05/08/upsert-lands-in-postgres-9.5/),  [this tutorial](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-upsert/), [this posting](https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/upsert-records-with-postgresql-9-5), [feature description](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.5#INSERT_..._ON_CONFLICT_DO_NOTHING.2FUPDATE_.28.22UPSERT.22.29) for Postgres 9.5, and [this presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pbg97bkxbbY) on YouTube.

```
INSERT INTO user_ ( username_ , password_ )
VALUES ( 'Alice' , 'pw123' ) 
ON CONFLICT ( username_ )
DO UPDATE SET ( password_ ) = ( 'pw123' )
;
```

Note that at least in the Postgres implementation, you can choose to do nothing if a row already exists.

```
INSERT INTO user_ ( username_ , password_ )
VALUES ( 'Alice' , 'pw123' ) 
ON CONFLICT ( username_ )
DO NOTHING
;
```

---

Of course I am ignoring the entire topic of properly storing passwords for users. I am sure this example in the Question is quite contrived and that you would *never* just write passwords.