# How to check whether user exist in database

Tags: java, postgresql

friends. I'm creating a mini bank application that user makes input with his name and id and then have several options. My problem is that i want to check if the user exists inside the insert() method to avoid duplicate and to have a opportunity to update the same user's balance while deposit and withdraw.

What i try with is this piece of code :

```
public boolean checkIfExist(Long id) throws SQLException { 
     
        Connection conn = null;  
        PreparedStatement ps = null;  
        ResultSet rs = null;  
                  
        try {             
            conn = connect();  
            ps=conn.prepareStatement("select * from customers where id=?");  
            ps.setLong(1, customerID);  
            rs=ps.executeQuery();
            if(rs != null) {
                return true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            System.out.println(e);
        } finally {  
            if (rs!=null) {  
                rs.close();  
            }
            if (ps!=null) {  
                ps.close();  
            }
            if (conn!=null) {  
                conn.close();  
            }   
        }  
        return false;
    }
```

and use it this way :

```
public void insert() throws SQLException {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO customers(id, name)" +
                     "VALUES(?, ?)";

        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;

        boolean ifExist = checkIfExist(customerID);

        if(!ifExist) { 
            try {
                conn = connect();
                ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                ps.setLong(1, customerID);
                ps.setString(2, customerName);
                ps.executeUpdate();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (ps != null) {
                    ps.close();
                }
                if (conn != null) {
                    conn.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But i get "true" everytime when execute it and cant insert a new customer. I guess the problem is in "if(rs != null)" but i dont know how to do it right.

Comment: Use `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`.

Comment: What is `customerID`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CheckIF Exist method**

- The purpose of this method is to check if a customer with a given ID already exist in the databse.
- It uses a SQL query to select records from the "customers" table where the ID matches the provided ID.
- The "executequery" method returns a "resultset" that represent the data retrieved from the database.
- Instead of checking if the "resultset" is not null ,it uses "rs.next()" to check if there is at least one row in the result set.
- If "rs.next()" returns "true" it means there is at least one matching customer, and the method returns "true". Otherwise, it returns "false".

**insert method**

- This method is responsible for inserting a new customer into the database.
- It first checks if a customer with the same ID already exists by calling the checkIfExist method.
- If checkIfExist returns false, it proceeds to execute an SQL INSERT statement to add the new customer to the database.
- If checkIfExist returns true, it skips the insertion step, avoiding duplicate entries in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate question
[java jdbc check if value exists before inserting into table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53733537/java-jdbc-check-if-value-exists-before-inserting-into-table)

Try like in above link. "select count(*) from customers where id=?"

Also useful article
https://www.baeldung.com/jdbc-check-table-exists